# Web Worker onmessage vs postMessage capitalization

Tags: javascript, html, web-worker

I am now learning about HTML5 Web Workers and I don't understand one small "stylistic" thing.

Why is `onmessage` with small `m` in `message`, but `postMessage` has capital `M`?

Is there some reason for this decision? I cannot find it.

I don't want an opinion on the styling, just some reasonable explanation.

Comment: This is my interpretation and I have absolutely nothing to back it up with: it's capitalized differently because if it weren't, it would mean something different. If it were `postmessage` then it would mean `after this message occurs`. It would be an event. However, if it's styled as `postMessage`, it means `send this message` (post it), which indicates it's an action. Now, if that sounds reasonable to you, great. If not, let's hope someone comes along and explains it better :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

camelCase is definitely the preferred convention for JavaScript. However, DOM events have been lowercase for a long time ([javascript/DOM event name convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19071579/javascript-dom-event-name-convention/19071821#19071821) posits a connection to case-insensitive HTML attribute names) and have remained that way for backwards compatibility for legacy browsers, and new events continue to follow that convention for consistency.

Check out [MDN's list of global event handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers) - `onload`, `onerror`, `onmousedown`, etc. This convention seems to have carried over into event names for things other than DOM events, but for stuff other than events, like the `postMessage` function, the camelCase convention remains.